# SQL Server alternative to using subquery in aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm using an aggregate function to calculate a GPA for a particular student. I have three tables: COURSE, SECTION, and ENROLL. These tables are created as such:

```
create table COURSE
(
    Cno     varchar(9) primary key, 
    Cname   varchar(50),
    Credit  int check (Credit > 0)
);

create table SECTION
(
    Cno     varchar(9) REFERENCES COURSE(cno),
    Sno     varchar(9),
    Semester    varchar(15) check(Semester in('Fall','Spring','Summer')), 
    Year    int, 
    Sid     varchar(9) primary key 
);

create table ENROLL
(
    Mno     varchar(9) REFERENCES STUDENT(Mno),
    Sid     varchar(9) REFERENCES SECTION(Sid),
    Grade   CHAR check(Grade in('A','B','C','D','F')),
    primary key(Mno,Sid)
);
```

I have to convert the char Grade in the ENROLL table to a float value. The way to calculate the GPA in my case is:

```
SUM(grade of each course*credit hours of the course)/SUM(credit hours of each course)
```

Here is how I'm currently attempting to calculate the GPA:

```
 @grade =     
(
 (select SUM(CASE 
              WHEN Grade = 'A' THEN 4.0
              WHEN Grade = 'B' THEN 3.0
              WHEN Grade = 'C' THEN 2.0
              WHEN Grade = 'D' THEN 1.0
              WHEN Grade = 'F' THEN 0.0
             END
             * (
                select c.Credit from COURSE c where c.Cno = (
                 select s.Cno from SECTION s where s.Sid in (
                  select Sid from ENROLL where Mno = @mNum
                 )
                )
             )
         ) FROM ENROLL 
         where Mno = @mNum 
 ) / (
  select SUM(Credit) from COURSE c where c.Cno = (
   select s.Cno from SECTION s where s.Sid in (
    select Sid from ENROLL where Mno = @mNum
   )
  ) group by c.Cno
 )
)
```

There is an obvious issue, however. You cannot have a subquery inside of an aggregate function, so I have been stumped trying to find an alternative.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Which table contains credit hours?

Comment: Sorry, I left that out! I'm using SQL server and have edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: COURSE contains credit hours. It's the `Credit` column name

Comment: use `join` instead of sub-queries..

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish Thank you... I should have thought about that but I'm really tired at this point. Add this as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would try is to join the TABLES ENROLL and SECTION first.

This will give me all of the sections which are associated with Mno.

After that i will join with COURSE table to get all the courses associated with the Mno.

select *
  from enroll a
  join section b
    on a.Sid=b.Sid
  join course c
    on b.Cno=c.Cno

Then i will group by the a.Mno. Which means i am calculating the GPA per Mno based on the computation defined.

```
**SUM(grade of each course*credit hours of the course)/SUM(credit hours of each course)**

select a.Mno
       ,sum(case WHEN c.Grade = 'A' THEN 4.0
                 WHEN c.Grade = 'B' THEN 3.0
                 WHEN c.Grade = 'C' THEN 2.0
                 WHEN c.Grade = 'D' THEN 1.0
                 WHEN c.Grade = 'F' THEN 0.0
             END * c.Credit)/sum(c.credit) 
  from enroll a
  join section b
    on a.Sid=b.Sid
  join course c
    on b.Cno=c.Cno
group by a.Mno
```

Comment: Hi, if you can help me fix another issue, I would greatly appreciate it. I am running an update statement that uses the local variable `@grade` which is the result of the above GPA, however it says that `@grade` contains more than one value. Do you see what might be causing that? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, I updated my code to reflect your changes entirely, and it made it work. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you just need to JOIN the three tables together:

```
SELECT ENROLL.Mno, SUM(CASE
    WHEN Grade = 'A' THEN 4.0
    WHEN Grade = 'B' THEN 3.0
    WHEN Grade = 'C' THEN 2.0
    WHEN Grade = 'D' THEN 1.0
    WHEN Grade = 'F' THEN 0.0
END * COURSE.Credit) / SUM(COURSE.Credit)
FROM ENROLL
INNER JOIN SECTION ON ENROLL.Sid = Section.Sid
INNER JOIN COURSE ON SECTION.Cno = COURSE.Cno
GROUP BY ENROLL.Mno
```

Comment: Hi, if you can help me fix another issue, I would greatly appreciate it. I am running an update statement that uses the local variable `@grade` which is the result of the above GPA, however it says that `@grade` contains more than one value. Do you see what might be causing that? Thanks.

Comment: If you're calculating `@grade` for one specific student (Mno) then remove the `ENROLL.Mno` from select, remove the group by altogether and add `WHERE ENROLL.Mno = @Mno`

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I updated my code to reflect all of your changes; I didn't recognize some of them at first. It works now! Thank you!